# how to display related field values into multiple columns in odoo 10?

Tags: odoo

How i can display Payment Journal (Credit / Cash) values in tree view of point of sale where this is displaying on form view in tab 'Payments'?

here is code

python file:

```py
statement_ids = fields.One2many('account.bank.statement.line', 'pos_statement_id', string='Payments', states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]}, readonly=True)
```

xml file:

```xml
  <page string="Payments">
                    <field name="statement_ids" colspan="4" nolabel="1">
                        <tree editable="bottom" string="Statement lines">
                            <field name="journal_id"/>
                            <field name="statement_id"/>
                            <field name="amount"/>
                        </tree>
                    </field>
                </page>
```

Answer (score 1):

field name="statement_ids" widget="many2many_tag"  You can try it on your tree view.

Comment: This widget only shows statement_ids_ids in tree view

Comment: You can make a new fields, that compute when "statement_ids" change.
Eg: https://codepad.co/snippet/ynAQOs34#. Then you show text_ statement_ids in tree views instead of statement_ids